# DHCP Lease Static IP

Tags: dhcp

Simple question but I've looked around for an answer on this. I add a `hosts {}` section to *dhcp.conf* to generate a static IP in a subnet. When a machine starts and is given this reservation, does this generate a 'lease' entry in the lease database?

My subnet is `192.168.0.0/24` with a dhcp range of `192.168.0.128/25`. Lets say my host has a IP reservation in the lower half of my subnet (e.g. `192.168.0.100`)

Comment: What DHCP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using dhcpd: No it doesn't because it doesn't need to (a static address isn't "leased").

The main purpose of the leases database/file is basically there to keep track of assigned IP addresses. If you have a manually assigned a static IP address in your dhcpd.conf the server won't ever dynamically assign this address and thus doesn't need to write it down elsewhere.

However, if your intention behind that was to see all active clients in your network, there are better tools for that, like arp-scan.